# Simple Segue not working in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am attempting a simple segue in my app using xamarin studio. I used the storyboard to initiate the segue using the "present modally" function, but every time I click the button to perform the segue in a simulator I receive the following error:

> Failed to marshal the Objective-C object 0x7f8018511770 (type: loginViewController). Could not find an existing managed instance for this object, nor was it possible to create a new managed instance (because the type 'iOSApp.loginViewController' does not have a constructor that takes one IntPtr argument).

Any idea as to what may be causing the problem? I have attached a screenshot of my main.storyboard file as well.

[image: main.storyboard]

The following code snippets are my `ViewController.cs` files and `loginViewController.cs` codes

```
using System;

using UIKit;

namespace iOSApp
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
     }
}
```

and

```
using System;

using UIKit;

namespace iOSApp
{


    public partial class loginViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public loginViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Your `loginViewController` .actor is calling the wrong base, change it to match the ones on my answer

Comment: And for the future, please do not add *screenshots* of code, add the code as text. It is searchable and easily reviewed by others, screenshots are not... ;-)

Comment: Changed question to reflect suggestions as well as code (as seen above) however, upon running in simulator same issue with same error code

Comment: That should work now, make sure you do a clean and rebuild all, delete the old app from simulator or device also just to make sure you are running the new one.

Comment: Clean worked, thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `LoginViewController` class ensure that you have the following constructor so it can be inflated from the storyboard:

```
protected YourClassNameViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{
    // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
}
```

If your class name is `loginViewController`, then your class will look something like:

```
protected partial class loginViewController : UIViewController
{
    public loginViewController(IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
       // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }

    ~~~~ rest of class
}
```

Comment: still results in the same error, I'm gonna edit the question to include screenshots of `ViewController.cs` and `loginViewController.cs`